# How to set initial values for Knockout's observables (for cascading <select> lists)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am testing out the very awesome Knockoutjs. I am facing a peculiar problem.

I found a similar question: [Binding initial/default value of dropdown (select) list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648991/knockout-js-binding-initial-default-value-of-dropdown-select-list), but it is not helping, as mine are cascading lists.

I make my initialModel as follows, using data from server.

```
var initialModel = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)) ;
```

Then I define my viewModel as follows.

```
    var viewModel = {
    evaluationGroups :ko.observableArray(initialModel.EvaluationGroups),
    SelectedEvaluationArea:ko.observable(initialModel.selectedEvaluationArea ? initialModel.selectedEvaluationArea.Id :null ),
    SelectedEvaluationGroup :ko.observable(initialModel.selectedEvaluationGroup)
}
```

Now, I want cascading `select` lists. Hence my binding is as under.

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Evaluation Group and Area</legend>
            <p>
                <select id="EvaluationGroupId" name="EvaluationGroupId" data-bind='options: evaluationGroups, optionsText:"Title", value:SelectedEvaluationGroup,  optionsCaption: "Select Group..."'></select>
            </p>
             <p>
                <select id="EvaluationAreaId" name="EvaluationAreaId" data-bind='options: SelectedEvaluationGroup()? SelectedEvaluationGroup().EvaluationAreas:null,  optionsValue: "Id", optionsText:"Title", value:SelectedEvaluationArea,  optionsCaption: "Select Area..."'></select>
            </p>
            </fieldset>
```

The problem is, I am unable to extract the initial value from my server data. If I see, the value of `viewModel.SelectedEvaluationGroup`, when the page has just loaded, with default values, I see `undefined`. However, if I see `initialModel.selectedEvaluationGroup`, it is the full object, as expected. What am I doing wrong? Is this not the correct way to initialize Knockout's observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have forgotten to run the applyBindings command?

i.e.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

#### Update

I have had a play with your jsfiddle.  Seems it is happy to bind to initial values when it is manually set to ones from the main array.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMvNM/5/

Comment: might I suggest you put together what you have in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for looking, Andrew. Actually, I have applied bindings; just I forgot to mention in the sample code above. Everything is working fine, except for the initial bindings. Have a look on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMvNM/1/

Comment: I'm still learning knockout - so I'm not sure why it wouldn't bind to the values you were passing.  I did get it to bind in the above answer though - strange

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I guess, for now I will solve my problem in the way you suggest. I think since the `selectedEvaluationGroup` or `selectedEvaluationArea` are different objects than the ones contained in the main array, hence the problem. Like in C#, we might have to define some way of checking the equality of these objects.

Comment: I wonder who down voted your answer. Is there any way to see this on SO?

Comment: no way to know in SO.  I don't really care about that sort of thing anymore :)

Comment: Hm.. no worries. Your updated answer does fit my bill for the moment. I will continue researching this and if I find a better solution, will post.

Comment: I'm not a fan of 'magic happens here' solutions.  Problems like these just highlight that we are using a library we don't understand enough yet

Comment: Of course, you are right about the "magic" bit, Andrew :) But I guess, I was on track about the `equality` thing. Ryan (of the knockmeout fame) has explained it here: http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/msg/9b7105c8606ef54e?pli=1