# How to pre-select an option in a dropdown knockout js

Tags: data-binding, select, initialization, knockout.js

I've looked at this other question, but can't get my select box to work correctly:
[Binding initial/default value of dropdown (select) list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648991/knockout-js-binding-initial-default-value-of-dropdown-select-list)

I've got the following Game object:

```
function Game(visitingTeamDetails, homeTeamDetails, game) {
if (arguments.length > 0) {
    this.VisitingTeamDetails = visitingTeamDetails;

    this.HomeTeamDetails = homeTeamDetails;

    this.GameId = ko.observable(game.GameId);
    this.HomeTeamName = ko.observable(game.HomeTeamName);
    this.VisitingTeamName = ko.observable(game.VisitingTeamName);
    this.SportTypeName = ko.observable(game.SportTypeName);
    this.HomeAccountName = ko.observable(game.HomeAccountName);
    this.VisitingAccountName = ko.observable(game.VisitingAccountName);
    this.GameDateString = ko.observable(game.GameDateString);
    this.GameTimeString = ko.observable(game.GameTimeString);
    this.AvailableSportTypes = ko.observableArray(game.Sports);

    this.sportTypeFunction = function () {
        for (sportType in this.AvailableSportTypes()) {
            if (this.AvailableSportTypes()[sportType].Name == this.SportTypeName()) {
                return this.AvailableSportTypes()[sportType];
            }
        }
        return null;
    };

    this.SportType = ko.observable(game.SportType);
}
}
```

SportType is an object with `Name` and `SportTypeId`.

I have the following template:

```
 <td rowspan="3"><select data-bind="options: AvailableSportTypes, value: SportType, optionsText:'Name', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" class="sportType"></select></td>
```

`AvailableSportTypes` is a list of `SportType`.

The list is coming in with the names of the SportTypes in the drop down list, but I can't make the initial selection be `SportType`.  I wrote `sportTypeFunction` to show myself that the data was coming in correctly, and it would select the correct value, but changing my selection in the drop down would not update SportType.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Anyone see it?

Thanks

Comment: Is `SportType` suppose to be the object?  If so, is `game.SportType` that gets passed in a reference to the an item in the `game.AvailableSportTypes` array?  Basically two objects are not equal unless they are actually a reference to the same object.  `var a = { name: "test" }, b = { name: "test" };  alert(a === b); //false`

Comment: Excellent point.  That would explain the behavior.  So I need to write my own compare operator? Or can I overload a prototype function somewhere?

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - I actually called sportTypeFunction again to set my initial value and everything works, including changing the option.  Don't know what I was doing wrong before.  Thanks for pointing out the object equality issue.  Any clever ways around that? My function feels hacky.

Comment: Not that it is way better, but in KO 1.3 you can extend `.fn` of observables, observableArrays, and dependentObservables to add functionality.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ZP79w/

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  If you want to move your comments to an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `game.SportType` gets passed in, it needs to be a reference to the an item in the `game.AvailableSportTypes` and not just an object that looks the same.

Basically two objects are not equal unless they are actually a reference to the same object.

```
var a = { name: "test" },
    b = { name: "test" }; 

    alert(a === b); //false
```

So, you would need to call your function to locate the correct object in the array and set it as the value of your observable.

Not that it is way better, but in KO 1.3 you can extend `.fn` of observables, observableArrays, and dependentObservables to add additional functionality.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ZP79w

Comment: I'm fighting with the same problem as the OP. Your fiddle doesn't work (it includes the latest version of KO). When I change it to include v1.3-beta, then it works again. Do you have any idea how to make it work with the current version of KO?

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the 2.2.1 and it seems to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ZP79w/.  Are you still seeing a problem?  Can you repro in a fiddle?

Comment: I don't understand... Before your update (using something like ko-latest-debug.js), it didn't work in FF and Chrome. When I changed the external resource to KO 1.3 beta, it worked. After your update it still works. I can't currently reproduce the problem.

Comment: I linked to the right copy of the latest release (2.2.1).  The current build files are no longer maintained in the project.

Comment: I think I have a repro of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/eNvGS/ . It's maybe not exactly the same problem as this question. Some seemingly unrelated code makes the ko.applyBindings() fail. -> see the commented part in the fiddle.