# Data-binding jquery mobile multiple select with knockout

Tags: jquery, dynamic, mobile, loading

**UPDATE**
I figured out why it wouldn't load the data into the select...my

```
 function company(name, value) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
    }
```

should have been

```
function company(name, value) {
   this.comapnyName = name;
   this.companyValue = value;
}
```

so it would match the expected structure in the data-bind...however it's still not loading at the beginning, but only after I select something does it change from previous three to those three loaded by the JSON call...*any reason refresh isn't firing?*

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to dynamically load some items into a multiple choice jquery mobile styled select but by using knockout.js as a backend...here's my code...it's working for when I load the viewModel in code (showing test, test1, test2 items) but I'd like to do load the items not on server-side, but on client-side, using the $.getJSON call bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-2.0.0.debug.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
</head>
<body>
Choose a company: <select id="companies" data-role="select" data-bind="options: companies,
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
    optionsText: 'companyName',
    optionsValue: 'companyValue',
    selectedOptions: chosencompanies" data-native-menu="false" multiple></select> 
<input data-bind="value: chosencompanies"></input>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function company(name, value) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.value = ko.observable(value);
    }
    var viewModel = {
        companies: ko.observableArray([
                { companyName: "test", companyValue: 0 },
                { companyName: "test1", companyValue: 1 },
                { companyName: "test2", companyValue: 2 }
            ]),
        chosencompanies: ko.observableArray(["0", "1", "2"]),
        resetcompanies: function () { this.chosencompanies(null) }
    };
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/service.svc/json/gc", function (json) {
        //var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(json);
        var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(json.GetCompaniesRESTResult, function (item){
            return new company(item.LongName, item.ID);
        });
        viewModel.companies(mappedData);
    });
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    $("#companies").selectmenu('refresh', 'true');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, even though the mappedData var is loaded properly from inside my getJSON call (which BTW is returning the following JSON:

```
{"GetCompaniesRESTResult":
[{"ID":1,"IsOnline":false,"LongName":"test1","ShortName":"t1"},
{"ID":2,"IsOnline":false,"LongName":"test2","ShortName":"t2"},
{"ID":3,"IsOnline":false,"LongName":"test3","ShortName":"t3"}]}
```

It's not showing up on the loaded page..once I click the selection button and I try to select something I will see that the chosencompanies input will hold 3 comma characters (but nothing in between, as it previously held ["0", "1", "2"], *which was my attempt of preselecting all the items loaded in the select* - which I also still haven't managed to do - so if anyone knows please answer also here or on [How to pre-select an option in a dropdown knockout js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449824/how-to-pre-select-an-option-in-a-dropdown-knockout-js/8778978#8778978)).

Am I assigning values to the companies observableArray wrong? Or is the value assigned somehow wrongly formed (even though it's passed an array) and shows up as such in the developer safari tools as Array[3]. Or maybe that refresh call isn't good somehow?

Please do help, any help would be appreciated, I'm mostly starting knockout and jqm now...