# select default value using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have defined my select as below

```
<select id="selProductType" data-bind="options: productType , value: editProductType , optionsText: 'Name'" />
```

Below is my code to fill the select in my view model

```
 // Loading combobox with Product Types
    $.getJSON("../RestService/Product/AllProductTypes",
      function (allData) {
          var mappedProductType = $.map(allData, function (item) {
              console.log(item.Id + ' ' + item.Name);
              return new productType(item);
          });
          self.productType(mappedProductType);

      });
```

When i initialise page i want to set default value to select. So  i tried below

```
self.editProductType(4);
```

But it gives me TypeErrror saying object 4 has no method Id.

How to go about it. I have also gone through similar post in stackoverflow but no luck.

[Knockout JS binding initial/default value of dropdown (select) list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648991/knockout-js-binding-initial-default-value-of-dropdown-select-list)

Comment: you have an extra " in select element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the :

```
optionsValue: 'Id'
```

in data-bind, the binding value in this case must be an object in productType array.

You can select the default object:

```
self.editProductType(self.productType()[2]);
```

---

**What is optionsValue?**

Similar to optionsText, you can also pass an additional parameter called optionsValue to specify which of the objects’ properties should be used to set the value attribute on the  elements that KO generates. You can also specify a JavaScript function to determine this value. This function will receive the selected item as its only argument and should return a string to use for the  element’s value attribute.

**Typically you’d only want to use optionsValue as a way of ensuring that KO can correctly retain selection when you update the set of available options.** For example, if you’re repeatedly getting a list of “car” objects via Ajax calls and want to ensure that the selected car is preserved, you might need to set optionsValue to "carId" or whatever unique identifier each “car” object has, otherwise KO won’t necessarily know which of the previous “car” objects corresponds to which of the new ones.

read more at: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: I added optionsValue in my databind and wrote as you said

self.editProductType(self.productType()[4]);

but i get error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Id' of undefined "

Comment: you have to make sure self.productType is an observable array has more than 4 items when you set this

Comment: self.productType is an observable array. But i didnt understood when you wrote self.editProductType(self.productType()[2]); 
what is this value 2. In my select list there will be 4 records and i will set 4th record as default selected

Comment: it's the item index. In this case: self.editProductType(self.productType()[3]);

Comment: ok i also did and it worked but like can we set to value which is coming from database. For example the select list will be loaded with value 1,2,3 and 4 with column called Id. Can we set Id = 4?

Comment: There's some misunderstanding, if you set optionsValue: 'Id', you can call self.editProductType(4) without any problem. Otherwise, you must call self.editProductType(self.productType()[3]);

Comment: If i add optionsValue in my select tag and use self.editProductType(4) then it gives error "Object 4 has no method Id". If i am going somewhere wrong let me know or i use other option you suggested

Comment: somehow i am still not able to use self.editProductType(4) even after adding optionsValue in select. Many thanks for your efforts. I really appreciate it.